# Windows UI Automation from a Web Page

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, automation, ui-automation

I have VB.NET code that handles automation of various application installs. I want to move this essentially out of a VB generated EXE package, and be able to execute the same code (or the equivalent result) from an HTML page on a server. Is this possible? It looks like javascript can't cross the web application/desktop application barrier. Perhaps I can execute the VB.NET code/application that handles the automation (stored server side) from code in the HTML? This is a fairly broad question(s) so ideas are welcome. Please post examples with your ideas!

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the VB.NET code supposed to execute? On the client computer or the server?

Answer (score 0):

Ian's comment made me read the question again. If you really plan to execute code on the client through a web browser, please ignore this answer.

You can use any server-side language that you want to do this. Since you already wrote it in VB, you can [use ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18773/Run-Interactive-Command-Shell-or-Batch-Files-From) or [PHP's exec()](http://www.php.net/function.exec). Example:

```
<?php
if($_GET["dosomething"]) {
    exec("mycommand");
}
```

will execute `mycommand` when you pass `dosomething` as a paramter to the file.

Comment: I want the webpage and the VB.NET application/resources to be on the server, executing code on the client to automate the application installs on the client.